# create alternate for jenkins master

Tags: jenkins

I would like to take suggestion and inputs from wider audience regarding an issue with Jenkins master

I would like to have Jenkins setup in the following way to have the other backup so that it runs even if the **master** is down!

[my plan for Jenkins master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUecM.png)

The black arrows indicate that it is the primary configuration for Jenkins1 master and if it is down, we can switch apache to communicate with Jenkins2 instantly as a hot backup

It is possible and can be achieved and is helpful while performing OS upgrades or any other maintenance activities on master machine

I am planning to have it in such a way that to have a set of Jenkins master, which can be used in a manner, that the load is delegated to each master from Apache and entire Jenkins is not offline when we restart a master as other masters are also online

Please let me know a better way to achieve this if you have any

Comment: It would be great to see an answer to this based on open-source projects.

Answer (score 0):

CloudBees have already addressed this issue with an [Enterprise plugin for HA](https://www.cloudbees.com/products/jenkins-enterprise/plugins/high-availability-plugin)

> The High Availability plugin, offered within CloudBees Jenkins
>   Enterprise, eliminates downtime due to master failures. Multiple
>   Jenkins masters act as backups waiting for a primary master failure.
>   Once a failure is detected, a backup master automatically boots up and
>   acts as a failover.The best part? Project work continues.

This is a paid solution but if you have a mission critical configuration then it might be worth the cost

Comment: Waiting for an available open solution and considering a solution of type apache cluster deployment with Jenkins